# Runtime error 70: Permission Denied

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am getting an error saying

> "Runtime error 70: Permission Denied"

Below is code in which I am getting this error.

```
Sub reconwebscrap() ' ' reconwebscrap Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R
    Dim requestsearchrange As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim entire As Range
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim revocdate As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tags As Object
    Dim tagx As Object
    Dim tags2 As Object
    Dim tagsx As Object

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    i = 0

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        Set requestsearchrange = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)
        Set entire = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    End With
the_start:

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'These attributes decide the position of internet explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Top = 0
    IE.Left = 0
    IE.Width = 800
    IE.Height = 600

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Disable the viewing of Internet Explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Visible = True

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Navigate to the website.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Navigate ("https://ibid.abc.com/RMT/MyDashboard")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Let the website load completely.
    'Error handling in case the website is not available.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Do Until Not IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Application.StatusBar = " Running"
    Loop

    'Do
        'DoEvents
            'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                'IE.Quit
                'Set IE = Nothing
                'GoTo the_start:
            'End If
    'Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

    MsgBox "webpage has loaded"

    revocdate = InputBox("enter the last revocation date")

    Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    'Set tags2 = IE.document.getElementById("dashboardSelect")

    For Each cell1 In requestsearchrange
        IE.document.getElementById("dashboardSelect").Value = "recipientSid"
        IE.document.getElementById("quickSearchCriteriaVar").Value = cell1.Value
        For Each tagx In tags
            If tagx.alt = "Search Request" Then
                tagx.Click
            End If
        Next tagx

        Do Until Not IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        i = i + 1
        Application.StatusBar = i & " Running"

    Next cell1

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

I am getting this error in

```
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.alt = "Search Request" Then
        tagx.Click
    End If
Next tagx
```

In this code I am trying to enter a number in the search box and then click on the button. Then wait for it to load and then enter the next number. But it is doing it for only first cell in excel sheet. After that I am getting this error.

Comment: to me it sounds like you are not permitted to access the IEdocument with the click event

Comment: What to do for this then?

Comment: But at the first time it is doing that.

Comment: I don't know the properties of the tagx object. But if you say it's doing it on the first time, only one element is locked or not permitted. Could you identify which `tagx` object throws the error?

Comment: For Each tagx In tags
        If tagx.alt = "Search Request" Then
            tagx.Click
        End If

Comment: Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")

Comment: Does your for each loop throws an error already at the first time or later?

Comment: loop throws permission denied error after the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the probably reason is the following:

At some point of your code you obtain the collection containing all elements with `img` tag name.

Later on the code goes into a loop. In every iteration of this loop one of this tag is clicked:

```
tagx.Click
```

I suppose this fires some JS script and some changes are made in the HTML structure. This causes the collection obtained before is not longer usable and it should be obtained from scratch.

So if you move this part of code:

```
Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

into this loop, it should work.

---

Here is your code with this modification:

```
Sub reconwebscrap() ' ' reconwebscrap Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R
    Dim requestsearchrange As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim entire As Range
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim revocdate As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tags As Object
    Dim tagx As Object
    Dim tags2 As Object
    Dim tagsx As Object

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    i = 0

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        Set requestsearchrange = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)
        Set entire = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
    End With
the_start:

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'These attributes decide the position of internet explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Top = 0
    IE.Left = 0
    IE.Width = 800
    IE.Height = 600

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Disable the viewing of Internet Explorer window.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Visible = True

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Navigate to the website.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IE.Navigate ("https://ibid.abc.com/RMT/MyDashboard")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Let the website load completely.
    'Error handling in case the website is not available.
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Do Until Not IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Application.StatusBar = " Running"
    Loop

    'Do
        'DoEvents
            'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                'IE.Quit
                'Set IE = Nothing
                'GoTo the_start:
            'End If
    'Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

    MsgBox "webpage has loaded"

    revocdate = InputBox("enter the last revocation date")


    'Set tags2 = IE.document.getElementById("dashboardSelect")

    For Each cell1 In requestsearchrange
        IE.document.getElementById("dashboardSelect").Value = "recipientSid"
        IE.document.getElementById("quickSearchCriteriaVar").Value = cell1.Value

        Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")

        For Each tagx In tags
            If tagx.alt = "Search Request" Then
                tagx.Click
            End If
        Next tagx

        Do Until Not IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        i = i + 1
        Application.StatusBar = i & " Running"

    Next cell1

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```